# What is the reactance when the frequency is 80 kHz?

Tags: capacitor, reactance

I recently had a test with the following question:

> What is the reactance of a 6.8µF capacitor at 80 kHz

I found the reactance to be:

\$X_c=\frac{1}{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot f\cdot C}=\frac{1}{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot 80 \cdot 10^3 Hz \cdot 6.8 \cdot 10^{-6}}=0.29 \Omega\$

However, I got a "wrong" on this answer but the instructor didn't give me the correct answer to the problem.

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong, and what the correct answer should be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pedantic and reasonably correct answer is 0.29256423362 ohms reactive and given that you got 0.29 ohms I would suggest that your instructor got the wrong answer or you have not fully stated what the question was.

There is a possibility that the answer expected was -0.29 ohms (as opposed to an inductor that has a positive value). See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance#Capacitivereactance) from wiki: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten about the `j` part in the denominator. If you are using j-notation and keep your equation in the complex/imaginary units, you have to preserve them.

In your case, with `j` in denominator, your answer should be:

\$?_c=\frac{1}{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot f\cdot C}=\frac{1}{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot 80 \cdot 10^3 Hz \cdot 6.8 \cdot 10^{-6}}=0.29 \frac{\Omega}{j}\$

Note that the `j` is still out there, I didn't just skip it.
Now, by moving `j` out of the denominator, it leaves you with:

\$0.29 \frac{\Omega}{j} = 0.29 \frac{\Omega \cdot j}{j \cdot j} = 0.29 \frac{\Omega \cdot j}{-1} = -0.29 [\Omega \cdot j]\$

(notabene: hence the minus in non-j formula) and again you can't skip the `j` just because it doesn't fit with what you think you should get.

Also, another thing is the `?`..

X stands for reactance, a real number.
Z stands for impendance, a complex number.
And there are no `j`s in real numbers.

The formula you were using is actually for capacitor's **impedance**:

\$Z_c=\frac{1}{j \cdot 2\pi \cdot f\cdot C} = \frac{-j}{2\pi \cdot f\cdot C}\$

and the **reactance** is a part of that impedance:

\$X_c=\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot f\cdot C}\$

and

\$Z_c = -j * X_c\$

That's pretty confusing until getting used to, even I messed it up when I was writing this answer and had to review&correct it. Formulas are quite similar, because they are closely related, and aside from remembering that Z is complex and X is real and watching out for `j`s, I can't come up with anything to make it easier to work with.